# Puppet agent unable to retrieve catalog from master when using ENC (ERROR 400 on Server)

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have a rather bizarre issue that I am unable to resolve. I have a Puppet environment that uses Foreman as an ENC via the /etc/puppet/node.rb script. The master is servicing roughly one hundred hosts. All but three hosts are working perfectly.

The error I get when triggering a catalog run on the three affected hosts is as follows:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on
SERVER: Failed when searching for node myhost.mydomain.foo.bar: Failed to find myhost.mydomain.foo.bar via exec: Execution of '/etc/puppet/node.rb myhost.mydomain.foo.bar' returned : 
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Manually running /etc/puppet/node.rb myhost.mydomain.foo.bar returns:

```
---
classes:
  bash: 
  common_packages: 
  cron: 
  customfacts: 
  fail2ban: 
  ntp: 
  puppet: 
  resolvconf: 
  ssh: 
  sysctl: 
  syslog_ng: 
  yum_repos: 
  zabbix: 
parameters:
  puppetmaster: mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar
  hostgroup: Base/App servers
  root_pw: 
  foreman_env: production
  owner_name: Admin User
  owner_email: devops@mydomain.foo.bar
  foreman_subnets: []
  foreman_interfaces:
  - mac: 
    ip: 
    type: Interface
    name: myhost.mydomain.foo.bar
    attrs: {}
    virtual: false
    link: true
    identifier: ''
    managed: true
    primary: true
    provision: true
    subnet: 
environment: production
```

Using curl to grab the node definition from the master works fine:

```
curl -k -H 'Accept: pson' --cert /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/$(hostname -f).pem --key /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/$(hostname -f).pem "https://mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar:8140/production/node/$(hostname -f)?transaction_uuid=701fa6a0-3240-42f6-8ea1-209b86535dec&fail_on_404=true"
```

Using curl to grab the catalog from the master also works just fine (this returns a massive, unformatted catalog):

```
curl -k -H 'Accept: pson' --cert /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/$(hostname -f).pem --key /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/$(hostname -f).pem "https://mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar:8140/production/catalog/$(hostname -f)"
```

Manually compiling a catalog on the master by doing

```
puppet master --compile myhost.mydomain.foo.bar > /tmp/myhost.mydomain.foo.bar.json
```

Copying the json file to the following location on the agent:

```
/var/lib/puppet/client_data/catalog/
```

And then manually applying it like so:

```
puppet catalog apply --server=mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar --verbose --terminus=json
```

Triggers a proper catalog run.

My agent's config looks as follows (this is the same for all hosts):

```
# This file is managed by Puppet
# Please do not edit this file

[main]

logdir = /var/log/puppet
rundir = /var/run/puppet
ssldir = $vardir/ssl

[agent]

classfile   = $vardir/classes.txt
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig

ca_server   = myforeman.mydomain.foo.bar
server      = mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar
environment = production

report            = true
runinterval       = 600
usecacheonfailure = true
```

My master's config is as follows:

```
[main]
    logdir           = /var/log/puppet
    rundir           = /var/run/puppet
    ssldir           = $vardir/ssl
    privatekeydir    = $ssldir/private_keys { group = service }
    hostprivkey      = $privatekeydir/$certname.pem { mode = 640 }
    autosign         = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }
    show_diff        = false
    hiera_config     = $confdir/hiera.yaml
    environmentpath  = /etc/puppet/environments
    basemodulepath   = /etc/puppet/environments/common:/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules

[agent]
    classfile         = $vardir/classes.txt
    localconfig       = $vardir/localconfig
    default_schedules = false
    report            = true
    pluginsync        = true
    masterport        = 8140
    environment       = production
    certname          = mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar
    server            = myforeman.mydomain.foo.bar
    listen            = false
    splay             = false
    splaylimit        = 1800
    runinterval       = 600
    noop              = false
    configtimeout     = 120
    usecacheonfailure = true

[master]
    autosign         = $confdir/autosign.conf { mode = 664 }
    reports          = log, foreman
    external_nodes   = /etc/puppet/node.rb
    node_terminus    = exec
    ca               = false
    ssldir           = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
    certname         = mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar
    parser           = current
    strict_variables = false
```

/etc/puppet/foreman.yaml is configured as follows:

```
---
:url: "https://myforeman.mydomain.foo.bar"
:ssl_ca: "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem"
:ssl_cert: "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/mymaster.mydomain.foo.bar.pem"
:ssl_key: "/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/myforeman.mydomain.foo.bar.pem"
:user: "admin"
:password: "mypassword"
:puppetdir: "/var/lib/puppet"
:puppetuser: "puppet"
:facts: true
:timeout: 10
:threads: null
```

Any advice or assistance would be highly appreciated!

UPDATE: I've included some info from Foreman's production.log below.

```
Started GET "/node/myhost.mydomain.foo.bar?format=yml" for 172.16.2.109 at 2016-07-14 07:43:44 +0200
2016-07-14 07:43:44 [I] Processing by HostsController#externalNodes as YML
2016-07-14 07:43:44 [I]   Parameters: {"name"=>"myhost.mydomain.foo.bar"}
2016-07-14 07:43:44 [I] Completed 201 Created in 283ms (Views: 11.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-07-14 07:43:44 [I] 

Started POST "/api/hosts/facts" for 172.16.2.109 at 2016-07-14 07:43:47 +0200
2016-07-14 07:43:47 [I] Processing by Api::V2::HostsController#facts as JSON
2016-07-14 07:43:47 [I]   Parameters: {"certname"=>"myhost.mydomain.foo.bar", "name"=>"myhost.mydomain.foo.bar", "facts"=>"[FILTERED]", "apiv"=>"v2", :host=>{"name"=>"myhost.mydomain.foo.bar", "certname"=>"myhost.mydomain.foo.bar"}}
2016-07-14 07:43:47 [I] Import facts for 'myhost.mydomain.foo.bar' completed. Added: 1, Updated: 6, Deleted 0 facts
2016-07-14 07:43:49 [I] 

Started POST "/api/reports" for 172.16.2.109 at 2016-07-14 07:44:48 +0200
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] Processing by Api::V2::ReportsController#create as JSON
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Parameters: {"report"=>"[FILTERED]", "apiv"=>"v2"}
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] processing report for myhost.mydomain.foo.bar
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered dashboard/_reports_widget.html.erb (80.0ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered dashboard/_distribution_widget.html.erb (38.4ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (125.4ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered common/_searchbar.html.erb (2.9ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered home/_user_dropdown.html.erb (1.0ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] Read fragment views/tabs_and_title_records-3 (0.1ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered home/_topbar.html.erb (1.8ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I]   Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (2.8ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] Completed 200 OK in 185ms (Views: 41.9ms | ActiveRecord: 117.8ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] Imported report for myhost.mydomain.foo.bar in 0.12 seconds
2016-07-14 07:44:48 [I] Completed 201 Created in 135ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2016-07-14 07:44:51 [I]
```

Comment: Can you add a copy of Foreman's production.log during the failing Puppet run?

Comment: The master typically runs without privilege.  It is possible that the user it runs as does not successfully execute the ENC.  That might happen simply because the ENC is not executable for him, or it might happen because the ENC attempts some action or data access that the puppetmaster user does not have sufficient privilege to perform.

Comment: Hi @JohnBollinger. That was my thinking initially, but remember what I said in my original post: of the roughly one hundred servers serviced by this master, only three aren't working. Nevertheless, I have run node.rb as the puppet user and was able to get both classes and parameters from Foreman.

Comment: @jonathanvdwatt, check your system logs for clues.  In particular, be on the lookout for SELinux AVC messages.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for the response. SELinux is, and has always been, disabled on this host:

`[root@myhost:~]  # getenforce` returns `Disabled`

Comment: Is production.log truncated? The POST /api/hosts/facts upload is missing a Completed line.

Comment: Hi @m0dlx, the "completed" is there. `2016-07-14 07:43:47 [I] Import facts for 'myhost.mydomain.foo.bar' completed. Added: 1, Updated: 6, Deleted 0 facts
2016-07-14 07:43:49 [I] `

Comment: No, a line starting with "Completed", like the other requests. Its absence suggests either the log's truncated or that the request is failing, which'd begin to explain why the ENC script is failing. It may be worth checking Apache error logs too in case Passenger or similar is logging why the request is failing.

Comment: @m0dlx, I've checked and that line is not present for any of my hosts- not even the ones that are working. I also have no errors in Apache's logs. Just tons of these entries: `[ 2016-07-15 13:56:54.4465 28309/7fc4043f3700 Pool2/Spawner.h:738 ]: [App 53553 stdout] 
[ 2016-07-15 13:57:11.3404 28309/7fc4043f3700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /usr/share/foreman started on PID 53553, listening on unix:/var/run/rubygem-passenger/passenger.1.0.50495/generation-3/backends/preloader.53594`

Browsing to `https://myforeman.mydomain.foo.bar/hosts/myhost.mydomain.foo.bar/facts` returns facts

Comment: The master also creates a node file at `/var/lib/puppet/yaml/node` which contains all this host's facts. This leads me to believe that the issue is somewhere between the master and the agent. It's as if the master is unable to pass the catalog to the agent. Or something like that.